# What are the prayers of Kunti to demi-gods for begetting children?

Tags: mahabharata, mantras, rishi

What are the prayers (verbatim in Sanskrit) offered by Kunti before begetting Pandava children ? Are boon manthras given to her by sage Doorvasa mentioned in Mahabharata or elsewhere?

Are they *Vaseekarana or Sammohana mantras*? in the name of a prayer? A sort of  ancient mantric seduction sashtra administered only by sages?

Is there any mention that these or other such mantras had been invoked once again at any point of time later under similar needful circumstances?

I ask this because in a long history such an event cannot be a one time occurence. Lord Krishna took an Avatar to help protect the Pandavas begotten this way in His fight against Adharma.

EDIT1:

Prayer is an article of faith in any religion, and when the answer comes in such quick evidence it reinforces this faith all the more.

Thanks for relevant references.

Comment: the mantras are secret for a reason. there are also bala & ati bala mantra given by vishvamitra to rama-lakshmana that can help you overcome hunger & sleep. imagine not having to eat or sleep and still remain active !! highly unlikely you'll find these mantras anywhere, cos we are not qualified to receive it. even if you do, there are a hundred niyamas to be followed when chanting them or it won't yield fruit.